# Returning a fixed row (number) of numbers in a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

In this data:

```
[‘23 2312 dfr tr 133’,
 ‘2344 fdeed’,
 ‘der3212fr342 96’]
```

I would like a function which would return values where there are  a certan number of numbers in a row. It doesn’t matter about spaces, or other text, as long as there are a certain numbers in a row. (No more, no less) For example:

```
2 numbers in a row:
[‘23’,’’,’96’]

3 numbers in a row:
[‘133’,’’,’342’]

4 numbers in a row:
[‘2312’,’2344’,’3212’]
```

Thank you

Comment: How are the data stored? In a text file as such? Or are they stored in any predefined structure, like an array, or a list for example?

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24878232/10197418)?

Comment: Imported to form a list. No external file. The list is a list of strings, like one at the top of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Why the empty strings in the middle of your first two outputs? Also, please provide valid data, your quotes are not normal quotes and will cause a syntax error.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if  the first string in list is "23 2312 dfr tr 13" if the number is 2.It will return `['23','','96']` or  `['23','13','','96']` or `[['23,','13'],'','96']` or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the contiguous digits from the strings and keep those which have length `n`:

```
l = ['23 2312 dfr tr 133',
     '2344 fdeed',
     'der3212fr342 96']

import re

def length_n_digits(l,n):
    return [s for i in l for s in 
            re.findall(rf'(?<!\d)\d{{{n}}}(?!\d)', i) or ['']]
```

Note that the double braces `'{{}}'` are just to escape the inner braces and no interpolation takes place. `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` are to lookaround and ensure that it only matches when the sequence of `n` digits is not surrounded by other digits.

---

```
length_n_digits(l, 2)
# ['23', '', '96']

length_n_digits(l, 3)
# ['133', '', '342']

length_n_digits(l, 4)
# ['2312', '2344', '3212']
```

Comment: But he wants to get `['23','','96']` when number is 2.

Comment: Should be ok now @jizhihaoSAMA there was a small detail I was not getting right that was driving me MAD :D